# Need several view block to send by mail on daily basis

Tags: drupal, notifications, message, newsletter

I have a requirement like - I have 6 view block showing on every user dashboard. The node list of those blocks varies from user to user according to setting.
I want to schedule a notification mail on everyday basis to send those view block in mail to every user of the website.
I have been suggested by some experienced member to set rules for it and send...but the thing is - what are things which should be set to achieve this?

If any body know the way to achieve it then please suggest..

Thanks,
RajeevK

Comment: Fago's these series will help you: http://dev.nodeone.se/node/984 (D7), D6: http://nodeone.se/blogg/learn-rules-screencast-series-summed-up

You will need Insert View module to insert the View or php views_embed_view() with some arguments (like user ID) set, and use Rules and Rules Scheduler to execute them. Not very easy to explain in 500 characters though. (Ask me why I'm not making this an answer: because it's not a good answer :)  )

Comment: I have seen those series..not much helpful in this case...though very helpful for knowing the power of rules & that's what gave me suggestion that I can achieve this functionality some how by help of this module...

Answer (score 1):

Rules and execution of custom php code by rueles scheduler can solve your problem:

```
$view = views_get_view('weekly_email' , TRUE);
$views_result = $view->preview('mail_embed');
$output = drupal_html_to_text($views_result);
print $output;
```

Comment: I didn't get your point...I have to write these custom code for rules to fetch the views according to user ID...& then have to set trigger notification for it ? But what about multiple views blocks and make that separate from each other ? 
But is there any way to set cron job for doing it at fix time given by me ?
Any way let me try this & see whether I am able to fetch it or not..

Comment: I tried this but it's just fetching the whole view block for the logged in user.
How to process the result of the view for each user separately when sending this in mail ?